# how to fix pine code for not generating trading signal?

Tags: signals, pine-script

i am coding donchian channel based strategy in pine script for trading view, all channels are plotting on chart as per the code but not able to generate buy sell short and cover signal and code also not showing any error , any help would be great.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Donchian Channel", overlay=true)

TOPLENGTH = input.int(defval=10,title='Top length',minval=5,maxval=100,step=1)
BOTTOMLENGTH = input.int(defval=10,title='Bottom length',minval=5,maxval=100,step=1)

midsellT = input.int(defval=10,title='midbuyT',minval=5,maxval=100,step=1)
midsellB = input.int(defval=10,title='midbuyB',minval=5,maxval=100,step=1)

midcoverT = input.int(defval=10,title='midshortT',minval=5,maxval=100,step=1)
midcoverB = input.int(defval=10,title='midshortB',minval=5,maxval=100,step=1)

hh = ta.highest(high, TOPLENGTH)
ll = ta.lowest(low, BOTTOMLENGTH)

hhB = ta.highest(high, midsellT)
llB = ta.lowest(low, midsellB)

hhL = ta.highest(high, midcoverT )
llL = ta.lowest(low, midcoverB )

Top    = plot(hh, 'Upper Band', color = color.green)
Bottom = plot(ll, 'Lower Band', color = color.red)

midB = (hhB + llB) / 2
midL = (hhL + llL) / 2

midPlotB = plot(midB, 'BasisB', color = color.black)
midPlotS = plot(midL, 'BasisL', color = color.blue)

buy  = ta.crossover(high,hh)
sell = ta.crossunder(low,midB)
short= ta.crossunder(low,ll)
cover= ta.crossover(high,midL)

plotshape(buy,style=shape.labelup,location=location.belowbar,color=color.green,title="buy",textcolor=color.black,text="buy")
plotshape(short,style=shape.labeldown,location=location.abovebar,color=color.red,title="short",textcolor=color.blue,text="short")

strategy.entry('long entry',strategy.long,when=buy)
strategy.close('long entry',when=sell)
strategy.entry('short entry',strategy.short,when=short)
strategy.close('short entry',when=cover)
```

Comment: I've tried to apply your strategy to AAPL,D & BTCUSD,D and didn't see any plotshape marks for entries. I suppose your `buy` and `short` never became `true`.

Comment: yes i know that signal is not generating that's why i asked the query how can i fix this what's are changes i have to make to make proper trading system if you know the pine script than please help to rectify issue i think signal condition is proper but some other issue is creating problem i don't know what.

Comment: I don't know the essence of your trading idea, but `buy  = ta.crossover(high,hh)` will never happens because `high <= hh` always.

Comment: my trading idea is simple buy when high of candle cross 25 period highest high and sell when 25 period lowest low break now i dont understand your explanation why always high of candle stay less or equal to 25 period highest high because 25 period highest is fix and we buy when it cross

Comment: This is because `hh` "includes" the `high` value of current bar.

Comment: so how to fix this give some suggestion.

Comment: `buy  = ta.crossover(high[1],hh)`

Comment: thanks for suggestion , i think its 'buy=ta.crossover(high,hh[1])' is right solution and how to buy on upper channel and lower channel as soon as its cross that price ,right now after updating code buy is placing on open of candle after close is above or below channel how to place buy sell on channel value?

Comment: after applying `buy=ta.crossover(high,hh[1])`

Comment: now code looks like this but still generating duplicate signals and also buying is happening on open of next candle after the close of candle above channel or below channel and same for sell and cover also how to implement the buy short sell and cover order on channel level itself when it cross.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/j2mESjgS